# Shared .purple directory with other user

Tags: permissions, pidgin, groups

I want to have this same archive of pidgin for two users. I figured out that I have to move existing `.purple` directory to directory available by both users, and then create symbolic links. But I have problem with first part

```
user1@workstation$ tail -n 1/etc/group
pidginarch:x:1004:user1,user2
user1@workstation$ cd /
user1@workstation$ sudo mkdir pidginarch
user1@workstation$ sudo chgrp -R pidginarch pidginarch/
user1@workstation$ sudo chmod -R g+w pidginarch/
user1@workstation$ cd pidginarch/
user1@workstation$ touch test
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: change folder permissions perhaps. Run chmod 755 .purple

Answer (score 0):

You are not pidginarch when doing `touch` so it requires `sudo`. So

```
sudo touch test
```

would be to do it.

By the way: I would not create a directory in `/` myself but probably use `/usr/local/` and then the sub-directory in there that is suitable for the file itself.

Comment: but according to /etc/groups, user1 is in pidginarch group. So why this does not work?